# Оборачивание всего socket.io в блок try...catch

Tags: node.js, socket.io

### Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть сервер, написанный с использованием фреймворка **Koa**, и к этому же серверу присоединён **socket.io**. Выглядит это примерно так:

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const IO = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')

const app = new Koa()
const server = http.createServer(app.callback())
const io = IO(server)
```

Далее на `app` я навешиваю множество `middleware`-ов, которые работают для запросов api с фронт-енда, а `io` занимается чем-то вроде чатов, которые входят в функционал всего приложения. Моя проблема в том, что если при работе чего-либо, связанного именно с `io`, происходит какая-либо ошибка, которую я не учёл, то это приводит к крушению всего сервера. С Koa таких проблем нет - если что-то пошло не так в ответ на какой-либо запрос, то это можно перехватить верхним `middleware`-ом ну или в крайнем случае сервер выдаст `500 Internal Server Error`, но **продолжит работать**.

Как реализовать похожий механизм с сокетами?

Answer (score 0):

Реализуй класс на сокетах, в котором будут все функции по ивентам (прим - hello), которые тебе нужны, а также метод инициализации и метод запуска.

```
init(io){
    io.on('connection', socket=>{
        socket.on('hello', ()=>{this.emitEvent('hello', socket.id)})
    })
}

hello(socketId){
    io.sockets.socket(socketId).emit('message', 'Hello!')
}

emitEvent(eventName, args){
    if (!this[eventName]) throw `Invalid eventName`;
    try{
       this[eventName](args) 
    } catch(e){
       //обработка которая нужна
    }
}
```